# Real set with every element as a limit

Tags: real-numbers

Is it possible to have a discrete set of real numbers $S$, such that for every $a\in S,\exists$ an infinite sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$$

Comment: Take perfect sets. Then all points in a perfect set are limit points. Example Cantor set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, The  set of rational numbers is not an interval and every rational number $r$ is the limit of the sequence $r+1/n$